# Undefined property of s?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I"m trying to get my sound to play but its not working because of s.play. the error says 
G:\Bullet.as, Line 10   1120: Access of undefined property s.

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip{

    var speed:Number;

    function Bullet() {
        var s = new ShotSound();
        s.play();
    }
}

public function Bullet(){

        speed = 20;
        graphics.lineStyle(7,0x000000);
        graphics.moveTo(-2,0);
        graphics.lineTo(2,0);
        graphics.lineStyle(3,0xff0000);
        graphics.moveTo(-2,0);
        graphics.lineTo(2,0);
        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);

}

function enterFrame(e:Event){

        this.x += speed;
        if(this.x > 600){
            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
            return;
        }

        for(var i in EnemyShip.list){
            if(this.hitTestObject(EnemyShip.list[i])){
                removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
                stage.removeChild(this);
                EnemyShip.list[i].takeDamage(1);
                break;
            }
        }

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re trying to call `s.play()` in the member declaration part of your class. You can only execute code within methods, for example in the constructor:

```
public class Bullet extends MovieClip {
    var speed:Number;

    function Bullet() {
        var s = new ShotSound();
        s.play();
    }
}
```

#### Update

In your updated code, the constructor and the `enterFrame` method are both declared *outside* of the class. You need to move them *inside*:

```
public class Bullet extends MovieClip {
    function Bullet() {
        …
    }
    function enterFrame(e:Event) {
        …
    }
}
```

So make sure that the braces are correctly placed (and no extra braces are at the end).

Comment: that did not work. I am now getting this error. G:\Bullet.as, Line 50 1087: Syntax error: extra characters found after end of program. 
And when I remove that character I get this error. .G:\Bullet.as, Line 1 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Bullet, enterFrame

Comment: pay more attention to your braces, this answer is correct